# Best way to bind DateTime to seperate date and time fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I use a model class with a DateTime value. I would like to display this property as two boxes, one for the date and the other one for the time.

What is the best way to do this? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the fields need to be two-way or display only?

Answer (score 2):

Check this [Splitting DateTime](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx) Blog post by Hanselman.

Answer (score 0):

Format your datetime in 2 diffent properties.

first to retrieve datetime format as "yyyy/MM/dd"
second format as "HH:mm:ss"

Comment: it's better to use date.ToShortTimeString() and date.ToShortDateString() since those are formatted per the current culture

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use two format expressions, one to extract the time and the other to extract the date.

Bind this to the date box:

```
txtDateBox.Text =  date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Bind this to the time box:

```
txtTimeBox.Text = date..ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

(Presumign your variable is called date).

Comment: it's better to use `date.ToShortTimeString()` and `date.ToShortDateString()` since those are formatted per the current culture. But the question is for MVC and I bet he want to use the strongly typed HtmlHelpers.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (I didn't run the code, it's only an idea):

```
private DateTime MyModelDateTime;
public string date
{
 get
 {
   return MyModelDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
 }
 set
 {
   string pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
   string timeValue = MyModelDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
   string dateTimeValue = value + " " +timeValue;
   MyModelDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeValue, pattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None)
 }
}

public string time
{
 get
 {
   return MyModelDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); 
 }
 set
 {
   string pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
   string dateValue = MyModelDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
   string dataTimeValue = dateValue + " " + value;
   MyModelDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeValue, pattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None)
 }
}
```